# Getting column names of each row in order

Tags: r, performance, apply

I have a dataframe with three columns of numeric values. I want to sort each row and print a string with the column names in sorted order for each row. Here is my code:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(3,1,2), d = c(4,0, 5))
> df
  x y d
1 1 3 4
2 2 1 0
3 3 2 5
> for(r in 1:nrow(df))
+ print(paste(colnames(sort(df[r,])), collapse = " "))
[1] "x y d"
[1] "d y x"
[1] "y x d"
```

This does work, but it takes a long time when I have a large dataframe. Is there a more effective way to perform the sort? I tried to use apply, but that just gave back blank strings:

```
> apply(df, 1, function(row) paste( colnames( sort( row, decreasing = T )) , collapse = " " ))
[1] "" "" ""
```

When I call the function within apply on a single row, it works:

```
> paste( colnames( sort( df[1,], decreasing = T )) , sep = " " )
[1] "d" "y" "x"
```

I am mainly looking for a faster way to perform this operation on each row of a large dataframe than the for loop. And I think apply could be faster, but cannot get it to work.

Comment: your apply failed because in the `apply`, row is a numeric vector, which don't have row names. when you do the same thing to a single row, the single row is actually still a data.frame, so that single row version works. Anyway, you may want to use the two answers using rank/order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x) names(x)[order(x)]))
```

This question popped up again in my reading, so thought shall edit to add more ways of doing it.. might help someone later :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, paste(colnames(df)[order(.SD)], collapse = " "), by = 1:nrow(df)]
```

Logic : groupby row index( means row-wise operation) - then apply `rank` to each group(which essentially is a row). `.SD` means subset of data( all columns)( you can control that too using `.SDcols =` argument. Then simple `paste` together the column names accordingly

Same logic as above implemented in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
       do(rank = paste(colnames(df)[order(unlist(.))], collapse = " ")) %>% 
       unnest()
```

Output :

```
#   nrow    V1
#1:    1 x y d
#2:    2 d y x
#3:    3 y x d
```

Comment: This essentially worked, but I had to change it slightly to `apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(names(x)[order(x)], collapse = " "))`

Comment: yup! awesome! I didn't see your expected output. apologise

Comment: @Anand just added another way of doing this.